# Omitting conjunctions

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation

"Meaning doesn't come from words, (        ) it comes from context."

This was my answer for one of the questions in my English test. But unfortunately my teacher said it was a wrong answer. The reason was because I have omitted a conjunction in the empty area.

So here is my question. Do you *need* a conjunction in that empty area? Isn't there a case where I can just skip that conjunction?

Comment: As your second clause is dependent (without the first clause, there's no reference for what "it" is) it would be more appropriate to use a semicolon rather than a comma. If they really wanted a conjunction, you could say **"Meaning doesn't come from words, but from context."**

Comment: Hello, Hank – << grammar / English / unfortunately / I  >> are corrections to other mistakes in your posting. Might I recommend that you visit the sister site ELL, which you may find more appropriate.

Comment: As it stands, your sentence contains a 'comma splice'. Some traditionalists would say that that is unacceptable. However, many (I'd say more enlightened) Anglophones are prepared to accept comma splices where the sentence is reasonably short and expresses closely related truths. I'd say that is true here. Barbara Wallraff in her book "Word Court" comments on the sentence _It's not a comet, it's a meteor._: '[P]unctuating this sentence with a semicolon would be like using a C-clamp to hold a sandwich together.' On the other hand, _Holmes found Moran, he was dead._ is best avoided.

Comment: I agree with Edwin Ashworth.  It may not be strictly correct according to book-learning, but it is perfectly natural-sounding in spoken English or informal written English.

Comment: I'm not sure that most speakers of English would really consciously recognize a distinction between a comma, semi-colon and period in spoken English. It's more of a relative degree and far more applicable to written English

Answer (score 1):

In this case, yes you can just "skip"  the conjunction. This is because the two independent clauses are relatively short and express "closely related truths." To quote the comment by Edwin Ashworth:

> As it stands, your sentence contains a 'comma splice' [connecting two independent clauses with a comma alone]. Some traditionalists would say that that is unacceptable. However, many (I'd say more enlightened) Anglophones are prepared to accept comma splices where the sentence is reasonably short and expresses closely related truths. I'd say that is true here. Barbara Wallraff in her book "Word Court" comments on the sentence *It's not a comet, it's a meteor.*: '[P]unctuating this sentence with a semicolon would be like using a C-clamp to hold a sandwich together.' On the other hand, *Holmes found Moran, he was dead. is best avoided.*

Answer (score 1):

While some modern speakers of English may accept a "comma splice" as accepted English, traditional grammar rejects it. You either need a conjunction or a semi-colon.

Given you specifically mention the context was an English test, it is fair to assume a stricter view of English grammar. You should learn the formal rules before you learn more informal ways which break those traditional rules.